# Windows 8.1 metro application crashes with HRESULT: 0x80040150

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro

So I created a windows 8 application and it runs correctly but when I run it on a 8.1 system it crashes. I also tried upgrading my application to target 8.1 and it didn't fix the issue.

This is the exception it throws:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in ******.exe

Additional information: Could not read key from registry (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040150 (REGDB_E_READREGDB))

Any help would be appreciated i am lost on how to solve this.

I did also try and run one of the sample apps for windows 8.1 provided by Microsoft to see if maybe my application was the issue and it behaves the same.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to read a read protected registry key. Did you run the program in the debugger so you could show the code where it crashes?

Comment: So I had it break when the exception gets thrown and it happens in this file: App.g.i.cs at this line: global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start((p) => new App());

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing issues with other metro applications, it may be due to Registry and or file system permissions. See the following Microsoft solution to resolve:

[**Registry and or file system permissions**](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2798317)